# I want to submit a form and update the values from the form (Mysql result) without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript

as the title says, I want to submit a form and update the values from the form (Mysql result) without refreshing the whole page.
See Image 1, I want if I press the blue button that the values updated.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

[image: Image 1]

Comment: look into jQuery ajax

Comment: Take a look at AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use newer apis like `Promise` and `fetch`, it's super easy and neat.

```js
foo.submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch("YOUR_URL", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      name: foo.user_name_value,
      email: foo.user_mail.value
    })
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json() // assume returning data is in json format, otherwise .text() could be used
  }).then(data => {
    // deal with return data
  }).catch(err => {
    // deals with errors
  })
})
```

```html
<form name="foo">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
  <div>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Send your message</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Older method XHR shares same idea, but requires a bit more code. You may use axios or so to simplify the process.